# Why Postman giving SSL error even the certificate date is valid?

Tags: ssl, postman, ssl-certificate

Postman is not giving any response when SSL is enabled while hitting an API, but showing response with disabled SSL.
 But my question is, the TLS "authorizationError" ="CERT_HAS_EXPIRED" but "validTo:" "Dec 15 02:30:21 2021 GMT" still have date.
Means still the certificate is in valid date.

[image]

Comment: Could mean that either the local clock is off. Or it refers to a different certificate in the chain, maybe a root cert has expired?

Comment: https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/

Answer (score 2):

You use let's encrypt. Normally the certificate would have expired today, but the have an extended period of live.

Postman has not updated our internal certificate store.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error. If you are completely sure your SSL is valid, then

> Update Postman to the latest version and restart Postman

Your request should work after that.

Answer (score 0):

Postman didn't update their internal Let's Encrypt certificate in time to handle [the expiry of the previous one](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/).

[They acknowledged it on GitHub](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/10338) and [released a patch on October 1st](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/10338#issuecomment-932256449), so updating your Postman client should correct the error.